# How to reflect data from the Get Request of Alamofire going to the UI View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I reflect the data from the JSON Dictionary using **Alamofire** to perform validation to check whether the passcode entered is valid or not to my UI View Controller. I already got a Successful result in getting data from the API but I don't know how can my view controller read the values from the API to validate the passcode entered. Please help me....... [image: Successful result in printing PasscodeJSON]

[image: eventDetails for ViewController but cannot read data from APIService]

**APIService**

```
class APIService
{
   let eventAPIKey: String
   let eventBaseURL: URL?

    //static let kEventID = "id"
    init(APIKey: String)
    {
    self.eventAPIKey = APIKey
     eventBaseURL = URL(string: BASE_URL)
     }

     func validatePasscode(passcode: String, completion: @escaping (Event?) -> Void)
    {
     if let passcodeURL = URL (string: "\(PASSCODE_CHECKER_URL)/\(passcode)") {


    Alamofire.request(passcodeURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value {
                print(passcodeJSON)
                completion(passcodeJSON as? Event)



            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error)")
            }
        }

       }
    }


 }
```

**ViewController**

```
func validateEventPasscode(){

    let api = APIService(APIKey: passcode)

    api.validatePasscode(passcode: passcode) { (event) in


        if let eventDetails = self.event {
            self.event = eventDetails
            self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEventDashboard", sender: self)

            self.enteredEventCode.text = ""
        }
```

Comment: You cannot downcast a collection type representing the JSON to `Event` (`passcodeJSON as? Event`). The types are completely different so `Event` is always `nil`. You have to map the array or dictionary (looks like an array) to your custom class. I recommend the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: @vadian Thank you. I'm new in swift and quite not familiar in some approach, how can I do the solution you suggested?